# Windows phone 7 image array

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an array of strings

```
images[]={"1.png","2.png","n...png"};
```

I am trying to set the source of my image to a image in the array.

```
myImage.Source=images[2];
```

I get the following error.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you cant set the string path to the source. Image.Source is expecting an Media.ImageSource which means you need to explicity create a BitMapImage and assign to the Source.

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(images[2], UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, the error message seems reasonable clear to me. [`Image.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) is of type `ImageSource`, not `string`. So in order to assign the `Source` property, you need an `ImageSource`. For example:

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(images[2], UriKind.Relative));
```

(`ImageSource` is an abstract class; in practice `BitmapImage` is the concrete class you'll usually want to use.)